How to change Caps lock shortcut from Shift+CAPS to Alt+CAPS
Debian Linux, which includes /etc/default/keyboard file to setup keyboard, both on console and X.
I have this line in it:
XKBOPTIONS="grp:caps_toggle"

Through this configuration, CAPS is used to toggle keyboard layout between american english and my native language layout. The Caps lock function is available with Shift+CAPS combination.
I also use sticky/dead keys, so pressing Shift will be remembered till next key press. Sometimes Shift is accidentally pressed before CAPS and instead of switching layout I start typing capital letters.
To conclude, is there any way to,

Switch layout with CAPS (as it is now)
Caps lock shortcut changed from Shift+CAPS to Alt+CAPS
Alternatively, disable Caps lock shortcut; I rarely type in all capitals.

